# How to structure the use of many views in a backbone router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm making a single page application using Require.js and Backbone.js. Its a fairly large web app with a lot of different "pages" aka views. Below is my router to give you an idea. There are several main pages with sub pages.

So for example there's a Settings section that has multiple different sub pages such as user settings, language settings, email settings etc.

**How would I structure many routes and their views for simplicity?**

Right now Im giving each sub page its own view but that means I have to import 20-30 views into the router so that all possible views are available for when that page is routed.

Another way I thought of was to have one view for each section and that in that view I should load different partials. That way I only have to load the 5-6 section views into the router... but then the view would have to understand routing.

**Whats the right way to do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create 'controller' objects that take care of view rendering and model fetches.
I prefer to keep the router clean at all times, which means that I will don't clutter it with callback functionality. Doing so would make the router a mess over time, while part of its purpose would be to get a quick overview of the available routes.

In Backbone, I found that it is useful to create your own conventions, just like a framework would do.
For example, for every view I create, I will create one controller object.
Every controller object has a method that is named 'makeView()', and which takes care of rendering the view, as well as memory management.
In my own theory, I created a method of 'cascading controllers', in the sense that one controller may also control other controllers, and controllers may use 'helper' objects to fulfil certain tasks. 
For example, when you say that you may need to manage 20 views and subviews; we could imagine that some of the views are related to each other; that there will be a central controller that takes care of common tasks between related views, and specific controllers that take care of specific, individual view functionality.

A route in my router looks something like this:

```
    auth: function(){ 
        //--- Check the authStatus and render status independent views 
        var auth_ctr = new Auth_ctr(); 
        auth_ctr.makeViews(); 
    }
```

In the example given, you could imagine that you will create and render multiple views. So what I really do, is instantiate new controllers from within this controllers, that each individually will create and manage views, provide functionality that support the view, get the collection/model data.
It would be important to create a sort of independent 'View manager' that prevents memory leaks from occurring when you render new views each time.

This is just how I do it, but of course, I'm sure there are people who do this differently.
It is a theory I came up with; it has given me a clear structure, and it has worked well for me until now.